# Displaying component dynamically by index inside ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a bunch of tasks and they have comments, when I click show comments on a particular list element I want to display only the component for that index.

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of todayTasks;let i = index">

     <li ..
       <button class="btn btn-info float-right"(click)="displayCommentsComponent(i)">Comments</button>
    </li>
    <app-today-tasks-comments id="{{'tasksComment' + i}}" *ngIf="showCommentComponent"</app-today-tasks-comments> 
</ul>
```

I don't know what to put in that *ngIf to display one specific element by index, right now it shows all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to have the `*ngIf` dependent on the index: `*ngIf="showCommentComponent[i]"`

```
<app-today-tasks-comments id="{{'tasksComment' + i}}" *ngIf="showCommentComponent[i]"></app-today-tasks-comments>
```

And then in your class, toggle that index on a map:

```
showCommentComponent = {};

displayCommentsComponent(index){
  this.showCommentComponent[index] = !this.showCommentComponent[index];
}
```

Comment: 'showCommentComponent: any[] = [];' I made this variable this type and it works but.. Care to explain a bit `*ngIf="showCommentComponent[i]"` is basically an element right? So I used the debugger and I can see an array of booleans, method inside that switches between true and false, why does that happen when I do statement inside displayComments method? I don't understand why the array is inferred as an array of booleans and just by negation statement with index can switch like this, this is so weird and cool

Comment: Yeah that will work too. The reason it does is because this: `!this.showCommentComponent[index];` will turn something that is undefined into true.

Comment: I've been blessed by one of the vanilla javasript gods haha, this was a very nice lesson to learn thank you!